# How to prefill inputs in omniscript

Tags: omnistudio, omniscript

I am trying to retrieve data (JSON) from record and prepopulate inputs based on retrieved value. I tried overwriting specific values by using Set Value action but Omniscript freezes when executed and I have to reload the page.

It happens only when I am trying to set a value for a node which is already assigned to some input.

So let's say node A:B:C is assigned to input C

When I try to set value to A:B:C before the step - script will freeze, but for A:B:D it will not as it does not exist.

Any ideas how to achieve what I need or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.